# Expressão regular: como aplicar "Negative lookahead" em apenas um grupo de captura?

Tags: regex, domínio

Em uma tarefa de validação de domínios, necessito de uma expressão regular para validar os mesmos seguindo algumas regras, dentre elas, em que o nome do domínio não contenha apenas números.

Diante disso, criei uma expressão regular (regex) que valida o domínio, porém não consegui fazer com que a mesma falhe em caso de apenas números no nome do domínio.

Em resumo, a expressão regular está falhando por permitir domínios que contém apenas números, pois são domínios inválidos e a expressão está permitindo os mesmos.

Expressão regular:

```
^(^[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,30}\.)?([a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)(\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$
```

Na expressão acima, estou capturando três grupos:

- Grupo 1: subdomínio;
- Grupo 2: domínio;
- Grupo 3: TLD.

Estou tentando aplicar um *negative lookahead* apenas no grupo 2, porém o [exemplo que encontrei aplica apenas no resultado inteiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831442/4921014).

Estou tentando aplicar apenas no grupo 2 (que captura o domínio), porém sem sucesso.

[Fiz um exemplo no RegExr](https://regexr.com/4sc9r) para demonstrar melhor o que estou tentando fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você colocar o *lookahead* dentro do grupo 2, e modificá-lo um pouco: [o link que você viu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831442/4921014) usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e final da string, por isso eles verificam a string inteira.

Se você não usar estes marcadores, o *lookahead* faz a verificação a partir da posição em que se encontra, então o grupo 2 ficaria assim:

```
((?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)
 ^^^^^^^^^ basta adicionar isso
```

Dentro do *lookahead* temos `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos), seguido de um ponto (`\.`). Ou seja, o *negative lookahead* verifica se a partir daquela posição, **não** existe uma sequência de somente números seguida de um ponto.

Como o *lookahead* sempre verifica a partir da posição atual, colocá-lo logo no início do grupo 2 é o suficiente, pois é a partir dali que será feita esta verificação.

Outro detalhe é que no grupo 1 não precisa repetir o marcador `^`, pois ele já foi colocado antes no início da regex.

A regex inteira fica assim:

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]{0,30}\.)?((?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)(\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$
```

[Veja aqui](https://regexr.com/4sco6) ela funcionando.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente! Acho que agora compreendi o funcionamento do negative lookahead! Muito obrigado mesmo!